# Can you explain me this part?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2016/05/juliette-binoche-kristen-stewart-cannes)

> Kristen is a young actress, and it’s very touching [for the French] to see somebody who doesn’t need to be here, because it’s not about money, it’s not about fame, **it’s about exploring different ways of expressing yourself,” the actress explained. “It is touching to us because there is a tradition here in France of making movies as an art form [rather than a business].** Final cut is given to the director, it is in the law here in France. A producer cannot have a final cut. It is in the law.

What does she mean by the bold part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**for him or for her, it's about {x}** is a colloquial way of saying "his or her motivation is {x}", or what he or she considers important is {x}.

The quotation is explaining what is "touching" or emotionally moving to the French, as the speaker (Binoche) understands the country. Stewart, a big Hollywood star, has no need of more fame or more money; she is motivated by aesthetic and artistic concerns, by an artist's interest in self-expression. In France, film is an art; it is not the producer who has final say on what scenes make it into the film, but the director, which is an  artistic not a commercial approach to film-making.